Reinforcement Learning Shape Error: ValueError: Error
I am using the below approach to create simple DL-RL Model, but I am getting this error:
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected flatten_1_input to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 1, 2)

I am using the following versions of libraries and Python:
Python 3.11.7
TensorFlow: Version: 2.13.0
Keras: 2.13.1
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import gym
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten
from rl.agents import DQNAgent
from rl.policy import BoltzmannQPolicy
from rl.memory import SequentialMemory
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers.legacy import Adam

class CustomEnv(gym.Env):
    def __init__(self, df):
        super(CustomEnv, self).__init__()
        self.df = df
        self.action_space = gym.spaces.Discrete(1)  # Action space (predict F_1_d_returns)
        self.observation_space = gym.spaces.Box(low=-np.inf, high=np.inf, shape=(2,), dtype=np.float32)  # State space (1_d_returns, 2_d_returns)
        self.current_step = 0

    def reset(self):
        # Reset the environment to initial state
        self.current_step = 0
        self.state = self.df.iloc[self.current_step, 1:3].values  # Start with first row's 1_d_returns and 2_d_returns
        return self.state

    def step(self, action):
        # Take an action (not relevant here as we are predicting)
        self.current_step += 1
        done = self.current_step >= len(self.df) - 1
        if done:
            next_state = self.state
        else:
            next_state = self.df.iloc[self.current_step, 1:3].values
        # Flatten the next_state
        next_state = np.reshape(next_state, (-1,))
        reward = 0  # No reward for predicting
        info = {}   # Additional information (if needed)
        return next_state, reward, done, info



df = pd.DataFrame({
    'F_1_d_returns': [-0.038076, 0.083333, 0.060577, -0.013599, -0.020221],
    '1_d_returns': [-0.062030, -0.038076, 0.083333, 0.060577, -0.013599],
    '2_d_returns': [-0.133681, -0.097744, 0.042084, 0.148958, 0.046154]
})

env = CustomEnv(df)
states = env.observation_space.shape
actions = env.action_space.n


def build_model(input_shape, nb_actions):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Flatten(input_shape=input_shape))  # Adjust input shape here
    model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(nb_actions, activation='linear'))
    return model

model = build_model(states, actions)

def build_agent(model, actions):
    policy = BoltzmannQPolicy()
    memory = SequentialMemory(limit=50000, window_length=1)
    dqn = DQNAgent(model=model, memory=memory, policy=policy, 
                  nb_actions=actions, nb_steps_warmup=10, target_model_update=1e-2)
    return dqn

dqn = build_agent(model, actions)
dqn.compile(Adam(lr=1e-3), metrics=['mae'])
dqn.fit(env, nb_steps=50000, visualize=False, verbose=1)


Hi @Tartaglia,The error you're seeing,ValueError: Error when checking input: expected flatten_1_input to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 1, 2), indicates a mismatch between the expected input shape for your model and the shape of the data you're providing.Make sure that state returned by the environment has a shape of (2,) and is properly flattened when fed into the model. Verify that input_shape parameter in your model matches the shape of your observations. Additionally, ensure that next_state in the step function is reshaped correctly to fit the expected input shape.
